# How to "prettify" my coments

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

How can I format my comments? For example, I've pasted a few lines of code (with new lines, spaces etc.) but it looks very ugly.

[image: Image of my comment]

Comment: What Robert said. And it's pointless posting multi-line Python code in comments because there's no way to preserve the indentation.

Comment: See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) , specifically the "How can I format and link in comments?" part

Answer (score 13):

Don't post code as comments in the first place. Edit it into your question or answer instead.

The purpose of comments is for [requests for clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). If you don't use them as intended then as you've seen they aren't a good fit.